# How to configure Firefox for NTLM SSO (Single-Sign-On)?

Tags: firefox, ntlm, single-sign-on

My computer and user belonging to the domain, I want to connect to my NTLM-SSO-enabled intranet website `http://intranet` without providing a login/password.

How to do it with Mozilla Firefox?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

- When accessing the relevant site you need to make sure you run Firefox as the Windows user you want to log on as. If you always log onto a workstation as a domain user then
  there is no issue, otherwise you may need to <kbd>Shift</kbd> +
  right-click the shortcut and choose **Run as different user...**, or setup a shortcut with your credentials saved
- In Firefox, type `about:config` In the address bar and press return.
- After the config page loads, in the filter box type:
  `network.automatic`. You should see a search result of
  `network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris`
- Modify `network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris` by double clicking the row
  and enter the relevent site
- Multiple sites can be added by comma delimiting them such as: `https://your_SecureAuth_FQDN.com,
  https://www.replacewithyourintranetsite.com`
- Click **OK**. You may need to restart Firefox for changes to take effect.

This is based on numerous pages I found on the internet, including [this Firefox support page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Firefox%20asks%20for%20user%20name%20and%20password%20on%20internal%20sites)

Comment: this does not work. i have read the same thing on many pages. is there an update for firefox v30

Comment: @sharif: Try using the downloading the following add-on: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/integrated-auth-for-firefox/ then click Tools->Integrated Authentication Sites and check the box at the bottom that says **Enable pass-through on all non-FQDN sites even if they aren't listed here**

Comment: @sharif: The issue that affects Firefox 30 specifically is that insecure v1 of NTLM has been disabled by default. It could be that you need to use the about:config editor to set `network.negotiate-auth.allow-insecure-ntlm-v1` to be true. However, NTLMv1 is very old, so I'm not sure if you would be using it. Relevant link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/30/Site_Compatibility

Comment: Nothing works so far. Whatever I try from all answers here, FF keeps popping that annoying dialog prompt with (already saved!) username and password. Very un-thought design on FF side, I must say...

Comment: Depending on the situation it might be worth trying with `network.automatic-ntlm-auth.allow-non-fqdn` set to true, although for me it still worked when set to false and not specifying a domain. Unfortunately Mozilla have made these settings far too numerous and complex

Answer (score 20):

To authenticate Firefox automatically through a proxy (avoiding NTLM prompt), you have to modify 3 parameters.

- Open the page about:config (in the address bar)

Add your uris (separate with `,`) in the following 3 parameters:

- `network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris`
- `network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris`
- `network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris`

and change it with the URL of your proxy redirection page, like http://myproxy.local

Modify

- `signon.autologin.proxy` to be `true`

If you do it by script, be careful with the dots (`.`) and the dash (`-`) in the parameters. This is often the problem.

Comment: network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris works for me. Eg. when https://subdomain1.companydomain.cz/identitity/auth is page where authentication through NTML is done, you have tu put value https://subdomain1.companydomain.cz (ie. protocol and full domain, without path). Note that values are comma (,) separated.

Comment: Works perfectly for me. My organization uses windows based single sign-on. Tested on firefox v61.0.2

Answer (score 6):

The suggested solution with network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris was not enough in my case.
Then I tried the same in network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris
Now it works.

Comment: Still not working: FF keeps popping that annoying dialog prompt with already saved username and password

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

Change 
**network.automatic-ntlm-auth.allow-non-fqdn** to **True**
and **signon.autologin.proxy** to **True**

Add *yourcompanyname.com* in:

**network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris**
   **network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris**
   **network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris**

Answer (score 1):

I modified **signon.autologin.proxy** to be **true** (by double-clicking on the preference name) and changed **network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris** to **timecard.example.com** and it's working for me, almost too well.  When I sign out of the page, it takes me to a sign-in screen, where I'm instantly logged in again.  But I can live with that.  What is missing is a way to either (a) add another URI with a single click, or (b) use wildcards, such as ***.example.com**.