# Configuration of Excel's Power Query "Trusted" data sources for windows authentication

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query, windows-authentication

I made simple WebApi, which returns data in JSON format for http GET request. The request is made from Excel (2013) through Power Query.

In order to receive a response from WebApi endpoint, a user has to be authenticated. Authentication is done via "Windows authentication". It means that the user doesn't have to enter a username or password. Client (Excel in this case) can just relay credentials for currently logged user.

Now, what is the problem:

When a user tries to refresh data first time, he or she is presented with [dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5XyK.png) for choosing an authentication method. All that is needed to be done is choose *Windows* followed by *Use credentials of currently logged user* and confirm.

Is there a way to avoid that? It will be used by many users and I want to minimize confusion (and requests for help).

It's analogous problem to [configuring a browser](https://superuser.com/questions/664656/how-to-configure-firefox-for-ntlm-sso-single-sign-on) to support *Windows authentication*. Basically, I would like to do the same thing, except in Excel.

My idea is to set it remotely with GPO policy or maybe import some registry keys. Is there a way how to do it?